# Is there a solution for preventing battery drain on the 5s after the iOS 7.0.6 update?

Tags: ios, battery

I have tried a hard reset, removing Outlook email account, and closing all apps and turning off Background App Refresh.

Comment: could you describe what you mean by "battery drain" more fully? What behavior are you seeing exactly that you want to prevent?

Comment: I mean the battery drains faster than it did before the update. When I unplug the phone and start the day, I observe the battery losing charge remarkably, even when it is in standby. If I browse the internet, say looking for an answer to this question, I lose charge at a much faster rate than before the update. There are multiple posts and articles out there (https://discussions.apple.com/message/25090364#25090364) about the phone getting warm after the update, but I'm not experiencing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered by updating to iOS 7.1. I've since turned all  the features of the phone back on (e.g., background app refresh, notifications, use my location, all the processes that I tuned off trying to troubleshoot) and my phone just lasted three days with normal use.